Design a Circuit to Obtain a 1.28V Reference Voltage for ADC0804
I am working on a project that involves interfacing an ADC0804 with a microcontroller for analog-to-digital conversion. The ADC0804 requires a Vref of 1.28V for accurate conversion. The available power supply is a 9V battery, and I plan to use a 7805 voltage regulator to step down the voltage to 5V for your circuit.
What is a reliable and precise method to derive 1.28V from the 5V supply for use as the reference voltage (Vref) for the ADC0804?

Pavan Freak - Hi, Please [edit] the question to show your own research and explain specifically where you are stuck. What research have you done about voltage references? Have you built one and it's unstable? Or consumes more current than you expected? Or something else? Please help people here to help you by elaborating more. || Please also link datasheets in the question for the relevant devices, to make it easier for people to help you. TY

I updated the question.

yes ...this is course project.....and use 8051 microcontroller

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The Vref/2 input can be forced to a different voltage to  adjust the input voltage range.

Most voltage references and regulators are designed to be stable to a varying extent against aging and temperature changes, not necessarily to have high absolute precision. The very precise references are trimmed at the factory and cost quite a bit because of it.
So, typically, especially for a one-off project, you will just choose a suitably stable voltage source, and trim it to a "perfect" 5.00V, 2.5V, 1.25V etc. as per project requirements. Once trimmed using a digital voltmeter, it will then retain this voltage quite well. Since it's an 8-bit converter, to have 1LSB of full scale error you need a 1.28V trimmed to within ±0.005V of the exact value. Decent 4.5-digit (or better) multimeters will probably be plenty enough to measure this voltage well enough to get the adjustment to within 1/200 of the Standard Volt.
Absolute voltage precision in off-the-shelf parts is best avoided unless the production volume demands it. The best voltage references out there are extremely stable but not super precise. Their stability is many times or even orders of magnitude better than their unadjusted precision. During the production of whatever device they go into, they get adjusted against a suitable "Volt reference".

To pull the ADC0804's reference pin down to 1.28 V, the circuit must be able to sink about 2 mA.
Using a resistor voltage divider would not work easily: the input resistance of pin 9 is specified with a tolerance of almost 50 %. A potentiometer between pin 9 and GND might work if you can calibrate it, but then you would still have temperature dependencies.
Zener diodes for low voltages are very dependent on the current and would also need careful calibration, so this would not be easier than just a potentiometer.
Integrated shunt voltage references are relatively cheap and widely used. They can be adjusted to have a voltage higher than their internal reference voltage. The very common TL431 has ≥2.5 V, but there are variants with ≥1.24 V; common ones are the TLV(H)431 or LM385-ADJ.

You will get precession voltage reference IC's for this application.They are available with fixed output voltage format and in  variable output voltage.
Below is the simulation of a fixed output voltage reference.

